# Sharing an instance of a class across a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a particular class used to interface with a service that requires initialization. In the application lifecycle, the only place this makes sense is in the start of the application because the rest of the spring application cannot run without it. I had the idea to do this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MyRequiredService mrs = new MyRequiredService();
            mrs.connect(); // This will throw if it fails
            run(MyApplication.class, args);
        } catch(MyException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to MyRequiredService!");
        }
    }
}
```

This will launch the service and attempt to connect but I have one big problem. How do I pass this class around the application? I need it's functions in the service endpoints I am writing.

I didn't see anything obvious and searching "passing class instance in spring boot application" turns up a bunch of unrelated topics.

Is there a smart, clean way to do this in spring boot? I apologize for a contrived example. The names of the service are unique enough I didn't want to violate any agreements.

Comment: you should `@Autowire` it

Comment: Ah!!! Of course, I had completely spaced autowiring. So I can just autowire inside of `MyApplication` the same way as any other class?

Comment: yes read some documents autowiring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make Spring do this for you. First, you need to annotate your class with `@Service`, so Spring will pick it up when scanning for classes.

Then, define an `init()` method and annotate it with `@PostConstruct`. Spring will instantiate your `MyRequiredService` class and call `init()`

```
@Service
public class MyRequiredService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        connect();
    }

    public void connect() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You *could* call `connect()` from the constructor, but I don't like to define objects that may throw exceptions out of the constructor.

And then, you can use `MyRequiredService` in some other class by injecting it via the `@Autowired` annotation:

```
@Component
public class MyOtherClass {
    private final MyRequiredService service;

    public MyOtherClass(final MyRequiredService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // Other methods here.
}
```

This has the same overall effect as what you're trying to do above. If `MyRequiredService` fails, the application will not start up.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a bean. Then it will be in the `ApplicationContext` which then you can pass to your desired other classes through the constructor

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{

    @Bean
    public MyRequiredService myRequiredService()
    {
        MyRequiredService mrs = new MyRequiredService();
        try {
            mrs.connect(); // This will throw if it fails
            return mrs;
        } catch(MyException e) {
            log.error("Failed to connect to MyRequiredService!");
            throw new IllegalStateException("MyRequiredService failed connection. Stopping startup");
        }
    }

    @Bean 
    public SomeOtherService someOtherService(MyRequiredService mrs) {
        return new SomeOtherService(mrs);
    }
}
```

IMHO Instead of catching the error and logging it. I would throw it and stop the application from starting, but to keep with your example I added the throw IllegalStateException after the log.

Doing it this way Spring will create your `MyRequiredService` bean in the `ApplicationContext` then you can see I added as a parameter needed by the bean below that. Spring will grab that bean out of the `ApplicationContext` and supply it to the bean. If Spring doesn't find the bean in the `ApplicationContext` it will throw an error and stop the application from startup.

Answer (score 0):

a class implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor which is init before normal bean

```
@Configuration
public class MyRequiredService implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, 
PriorityOrdered, InitializingBean {

@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}

public void connect() {
    // ...
}


@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

}


@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        connect();
}
```

}